# Wireless Internet Mapped Network Drives at Boot

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, network-shares

My HTPC maps my drives (automatically on boot) from my main computer so I can stream my videos to my TV. It works fine using ethernet. However I switched over to my wireless card and when I restart windows, after it boots, it pops up a message saying it was unable to map my network drives.

My assumption is that it can't connect to the wireless before it tries to map the drives, because right after it gives that message I can go to my computer and just click on the mapped drives and it will mount them properly.

Is there any way to have windows delay trying to map the drives until after I get the wireless up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suprising that this issue hasn't been addressed yet.

[This post in 2004](https://web.archive.org/web/20090612134231/http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/network-drive-connection/94686.html) asks the same thing and gets the answer of writing a delayed batch script.

> Unfortunately, a wireless connection has problems mapping a network
>   drive. I have faced the exact situation and, as far as I know, there
>   is only one cure. You must run the mapping manually after the wireless
>   connection is made. I use a batch file which makes the connection. For
>   example, I use the "net use" command:
>
> `net use f: \\computername\sharedfolder`
>
> That will map the shared folder as the f:
>   drive. I have contacted D-Link and Linksys for assistance in this
>   regard and they have suggested the same solution. For more
>   information, at the command promopt type `net use /?`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.  *Yes* I realize an edit is pending or has been approved, to include the content into the answer, but the original link died and that is the problem with link only answers.

Comment: @Ramhound And if the page hadn't been archived there'd be little to salvage in the answer.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan - I 100% agree.  Personally if this wasn't the accepted answer I would have flagged the answer.  Since it is the accepted answer there is little reason to do that, since it won't be deleted, since it is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could always map your drives with a delayed batch script? :)

see [this link](http://www.tutorial5.com/content/view/157/47/) to create a startup script in win 7